# C# ASP.Net API Json response, how to get double as values

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, formatting

I am trying to create an API that should return a Json of the type:

```
[{"property1" : value, "property2" : value, ...},{}]
```

but the output of the API is returning doubles as if they were strings in the Json:

```
[{"property1" : "value", "property2" : "value", ...},{}]
```

The Json is created from a DataTable with a GET controller function like:

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
            DataTable DT = GetDataTable();
            return DT;
}
```

and I have the following configuration in Global.asax.cs:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Does anyone know how I can configure the output to have this done right?

I would need to have values as numeric values for the client application to work properly with them...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Then don't return a `DataTable`, create a class that represents your data correctly.

Comment: The issue I have with that is that: 1. number of properties changes from case to case; 2. property names might change also; 3. result will always be a mix of properties some as Double, some as strings. A DataTable is an easy way to collect all these...

Comment: There's always a better way than a `DataTable`, that's a legacy component that is rarely used today.

Comment: Don't think that the Datatable -> JSON will output anything other than text versions of the data. So your client will need to convert it.

Comment: Finally found a way by adding the type to the column when adding these: e.g. dt.Columns.Add(property, typeof(double)). In case anyone else struggles with the same issue :)